# Problem sending email through stmpjs and elastic mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email through my node JS application, and I have this script in one of my pages.

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendEmail(){console.log(Email)
        Email.send({
            SecureToken:'#########',
            To: `mymail@gmail.com`,
            From: "info@example.com",
            Subject: "Hello world",
            Body: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`
        }).then(response => {
            alert(response)
        });
    }
</script>
<button onclick="sendEmail()">Send email</button>
```

I get as response OK, but no email is being sent. Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe is because smpt only works with trust API's.

```
function sendEmail(){
            Email.send({
                Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
                Username : "elasticmailuser@mail.com",
                Password : "password given by elasticmail",
                To : 'mymail@mail.com',
                From : 'your username',
                Subject : document.getElementById("subject").value,
                Body : getElementById("body").value
            }).then(
            message => alert("Message send succesfully!")
            );
        }
```

Hope it helps